# Dell D6000 DisplayLink dock blanks screens

Tags: 18.04, display, displaylink

after a period of time that ranges from minutes to hours, the two external displays i have will go blank. everything else connected to the dock still works. I'm running ubunu 18.04 on an Acer A515 with NVIDIA MX150 using the *proprietary driver*.

Edit: Well I thought I was using the proprietary driver. It looks like I had nouveau installed. I verified by using the    `sudo lshw -c video` command and installed nvidia via the software and updates panel with a reboot. 20 min in and all seems well. Everything is a little smoother. I previously wasn't able to shut down the laptop with the dock connected. After installing the nvidia driver I was able to shut down.

Update 2: So while the issue is now less frequent it still persists. I tried restarting this morning and had to disconnect the USB-C cable from the laptop to get the system to reboot. A new issues has crept up where an area approx 36 by 36 pixels freezes around the cursor. I have to move the mouse to get the screen to update around it, then it freezes again. Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: I am having this same issue as well, though it only happens on the two DisplayPort monitors.

Comment: Same Issue, still no fix out there. (Dell Latitude 5590 - Dell D6000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution seemed to be a combination of the latest nvidia driver and the latest displaylink driver.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the monitors connected to the D6000 going blank after a while, the following fix worked for me.

Edit the following line in: /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
# load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

I've also read about and changed the following line in /etc/default/grub.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

Comment: Using the latest driver from displaylink has also helped. I haven't experienced this issue in a long time.

Comment: This happens at least once a day for me - I'm going to try the default.pa, then the GRUB if it doesn't resolve it. Thanks / will report back :P

Comment: Back - the change to /etc/pulse/default.pa has resolved my occasional dock issues, TYVM Tim. I didn't need the GRUB statement