# DisplayPort Monitors No Longer Detected

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I've been using Ubuntu 18.04 with my Dell notebook and 2 DisplayPort monitors connected via Dell D6000  USB-C dock for ~8 months with no issues. Today I plugged in like normal, but Ubuntu can't find the monitors any more. The laptop is dual boot, and the monitors still work fine in Windows 10. It has integrated Intel HD Graphics 620 graphics. I tried switching to lightdm but it didn't help.

`xrandr` shows DP-1 and DP-2 disconnected, though they are plugged in.

The dock has one HDMI port, and it is still working. I can plug in one monitor to it and Ubuntu uses it just fine.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: In my experience, when that starts happening, checking for (and installing) system updates and then restarting often stops it from happening, at least for a while. So that's at least worth trying.

Comment: Thanks Amanda; I've tried that several times since the original post, but still seeing the same problem.

Comment: I have this problem perennially, which is exhausting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly different issue, but hopefully some of this applies.

I had a brand new **Debian 10.4** install on a **Dell** laptop (**Latitude 5590**), and was having issues getting external display ports working with the **Dell D6000 dock**.

The solution for me has been to:

1. Ensure secure boot is turned off in the BIOS (I also enabled legacy support - not sure if this is required)
2. [Install the displaylink driver for ubuntu](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu) (5.3.1)
3. Create a file to persist xorg configuration ([source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DisplayLink)):

`/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45custom_xrandr-settings` containing ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125613/54089)):

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 2 0
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 3 0
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 4 0
xrandr --output DVI-I-3-2 --mode 1920x1080
xrandr --output DVI-I-2-1 --mode 1920x1080
```

(You made need to run `xrandr -q` to check what your outputs are)

4. Modify `/etc/pulse/default.pa` ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1191089/193732)) to avoid my Dock being suspended (screens turn off seemingly randomly), placing a comment `#` before `load-module module-suspend-on-idle`, then restart my laptop

I know to avoid Dell docks in the future.

Comment: Upgrading to version 5.3 of the displaylink driver fixed the issue for me. Thanks

Comment: But now Ubuntu randomly logs out. Seems like others have had this issue and found Nvidia graphics drivers to be at fault. My PC used integrated Intel graphics.

Comment: Hmm maybe check system logs, almost sounds like something is crashing and taking the user session process with it? Sorry, sounds like we had separate issues. Maybe differences between Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: For me, it was disabling secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Dell Precision 7520, Ubuntu 20.04, I even ordered another PR03X dock station :D

Helped reinstalling, resp. changing display driver.

- Go to Software Updates
- Settings
- Additional Drivers
- I had Nouveau by default, changed to NVIDIA driver metapackage 510 and voila :)